# Yui hide and show nodes

Tags: yui, yui3

in this example its replace the div container with other element but its get the other element from the yui function how can i make same example but with replace two divs in the html

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo">
    <p><em>Click me.</em></p>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
YUI({ filter: 'raw' }).use("node", function(Y) {
    var node = Y.one('#demo p');

    var onClick = function(e) {
        // e.target === node || #demo p em
        var tag = e.target.get('parentNode.tagName');

        // e.currentTarget === node
        e.currentTarget.one('em').setContent('I am a child of ' + tag + '.');
    };

    node.on('click', onClick);
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? This isn't replacing any divs: when you click the "Click me.", it replaces the "Click me." content with "I am a child of div."

Comment: Yes. Please clarify.  Exactly what result do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, You'd like to replace another div or select another div?

In this example, `em` is selected and then its content is changed by `setContent( "your new content" )`

You can just select the `e.currentTarget` (the node or #demo p div) and `setHTML()` and build your div inside like string for example `<div>content<div>`, this is just one out of millions of ways to accomplish this.

have a look to this: http://www.jsrosettastone.com/